# How to escape ampersand character in C programming?

Tags: c, escaping, ampersand

I want to pass a url containing ampersand sign to a shell script using C program.  So I have to create the url string and pass it to shell script using system call . How can I escape ampersand character while making string in C?  To pass to script I have  to escape ampersand sign. How can it be done?  It tried with \&.  But it threw error

Comment: "it threw error" ? where? which error? try `\\&`

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "esacping the & character"? Show your code and show the exact error you get and show an example of what you want.

Comment: There's no problem using `&` inside strings in C. Is this question really about C, or about something else, like Unix shellscripts?

Comment: `&` needs not to be escaped on the C side. If you type `\&` in C it won't work either. You need `\\&`

Comment: Oh yes, it's not a C question.

Comment: Have you tried putting the URL inside single quotes rather than escaping the ampersand?

Comment: it's somehow a C question: something like: how to issue `\&` to a sub-process?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `\&` to the shell.

If you try

```
"echo \&\n"
```

from the C side, since `\&` isn't a valid escape sequence you get an error from the compiler. What you *really* need to escape from the C side is the backslash:

For instance try this code:

```
printf("echo \\&\n");
```

you'll see that `\&` is printed (so it will also work from a `system` call), which seems to be what you want.

Another method that works only on unix-like shells it to protect the argument with single quotes:

```
printf("echo '&'\n");
```

Note that it doesn't work in Windows because Windows doesn't consider single quotes as quotes.

something that works everywhere as well: protect in (escaped) double quotes:

```
printf("echo \"&\"\n");
```

Comment: Or use single quotes around the ampersand; there are usually fewer problems with those.

Comment: single quotes are okay when using underlying bash. On windows it doesn't work (and `&` is also a special character)

Answer (score 0):

```
code is as follows

sprintf ( url, "http://%s:%d/device_mgr/device-mgmt/app/cnc/sno/%s/updates?
cur_fw_ver=%s\\&cur_config_ver=%s", url_detail -> ip, url_detail -> port_no, 
serial_number, fw_current_version, CONFIG_VERSION );

status = bhel_cfgmgr_download_upgrade_json( url );

and the api calls a shell script:


nos_int32 bhel_cfgmgr_download_upgrade_json (nos_char* url)
{

    nos_int32    status      = 0;
    nos_char     *cmd_buffer = NULL;
    nos_int32    buffer_size = 0;

    buffer_size = nos_strlen(url) + 100;

    cmd_buffer = (nos_char *)nos_malloc(buffer_size);
    if (cmd_buffer == NULL) {
        return (-1);
    }

    nos_memset(cmd_buffer,0,buffer_size);

    sprintf(cmd_buffer, "%s  %s %s", JSON_DWLD_SCRIPT, JSON_DOWNLOAD, url );

    nos_dbg_log(NOS_DBG_INFO, " script command : %s \n", cmd_buffer);

    status = system(cmd_buffer);


    nos_free(cmd_buffer);

    return (status);


}


shell script :


#!/bin/sh
#
#
#

download_json ()
{
echo $1
    download_file=$1
    # Check whether we have this directory. If so, remove this and re-create this.

    if [ -d /tmp/bhel_downloads ]; then
            rm -rf /tmp/bhel_downloads
    fi

    mkdir /tmp/bhel_downloads
    cd /tmp/bhel_downloads

    # Now download the json file

    wget ${download_file} -O upgrade_details.json  --timeout 1 -q

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "upgrade json file download failed"
        return 1;
    fi

    if [ ! -f /tmp/bhel_downloads/upgrade_details.json ]; then
        echo "upgrade json file not found"
        return 1
    fi


    return 0
}

case $1 in

    download)
        download_json $2
        ;;

esac
```